# How to know the possible order of a coset when an order of an element is given?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a group $G$ and an element $a\in{G}$ which has an order of 17 ( o(a)=17 ). Also I'm giving that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and I'm supposed to know the possible orders of the right coset $Ha$ from this given.

I'm trying to better my understanding of the order of a group and using [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

I'm not seeing a way to approach this, from the given I figured out that if $H$ is a normal subgroup then $\forall{h}\in{H},\forall{}a\in{H}$ it is known that $a*h*a^{-1}\in{H}$ where * is the operation of $G$, and also it is known that the right and left cosets are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the coset divides the order of a representative (by Lagrange's theorem). So the answer is 17 (if your element is not in the normal subgroup) or 1 (otherwise).

Comment: To understand better from Lagrange I have that o(H) must divide o(G). and since 17 is prime it can only be 17 ? and also only o(a)=17 does that mean so is o(G)?

Comment: The cyclic subgroup $C'$  of the quotient group generated by the coset is a homomorphic image of the cyclic subgroup $C$ of the original group generated by the representative. So by Lagrange the order of $C'$ divides the order of $C$ which is 17.Hence the order of $C'$ is 17 or 1.

Comment: Can you please go into detail in the answer for the two cases that you've mentioned ?

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: I don't fully understand how you reached that the coset is cyclic.

Comment: I consider the cyclic subgroup generated by the coset. You need to count the number of elements in that cyclic group.

Comment: @user3133165: A coset cannot be cyclic.